# Android R14 SDK - Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value...)

Tags: android, xml, background

I searched a lot of time for a fix, but don't find an answer.

Since I've updated the Android SDK to R14 (Android 4.0), I get the Error `"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background with value '@layout/card_top').`

The Part in my xml-file is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_top_bkg"      
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/card_top" 
    android:layout_weight="2">
```

The "card_top.xml" file is in an separate library-folder and not in the same filder as the base project. If i put the card_top.xml file directly under layout/card_top.xml in the base project folder, it works.

Knows anyone how to get it working with leaving the xml-file in the library-folder?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is solved in r15, it's just a bug fix release:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html#
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#